# Identifying what type of capacitor

Tags: capacitor

[image]

The markings are 5L = 104 and I can’t find much about it online.

Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: There are many different types of capacitors visible in that photo. The tall cylindrical ones are radial leaded aluminum electrolytic capacitors. The shorter silvery cylindrical ones are surface-mount aluminum electrolytics. The red rectangular one near the center is a radial leaded ceramic capacitor. The small rectangular ones with silver end-caps are surface-mount ceramic capacitors.  For ceramic caps, the "104" marking is a commonly used picofarad code:1.0 with 4 more zeroes, 100000pF or 100nF or 0.1uF. Check mouser or element14 for ceramic 0.1uF radial leaded capacitor.

Comment: Ceramic...or film?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a 100nF dipped film capacitor, probably rated at 50VDC.

Similar to this Panasonic one [ECQ-V1H104JL3](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECQV(L,M).pdf):

[image]